# Ratio limit of moments for bounded functions

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification

I would appriciate if someone could verify if my solution to the following problem is correct.

Problem:
Given the measure space $\left(X,\mathcal{F},\mu\right)$, where $\mu(X)<\infty
 $ and a function $f\in L^{\infty}(\mu)
 $, show that $\lim_{n}\frac{\int\left|f\right|^{n+1}d\mu}{\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu}=\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\infty}
 $.

My solution:

On one hand we have,
$\frac{\int\left|f\right|^{n+1}d\mu}{\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu}\leq\frac{\int\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\infty}\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu}{\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu}=\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\infty}\cdot1
. $

But on the other hand we have,
$\frac{\int\left|f\right|^{n+1}d\mu}{\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu}=\frac{\int\left|f\right|^{n\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}d\mu/\mu(X)}{\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu/\mu(X)}\geq[Jensen]\geq\frac{\left(\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu/\mu(X)\right)^{^{\left(\frac{n+1}{n}\right)}}}{\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu/\mu(X)}=\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{n}\mu(X)^{-1/n}.
 $

From which it follows that

$\lim_{n}\frac{\int\left|f\right|^{n+1}d\mu}{\int\left|f\right|^{n}d\mu}\geq\lim_{n}\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{n}\mu(X)^{-1/n}=\lim_{n}\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{n}\lim_{n}\mu(X)^{-1/n}=\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\infty}\cdot1
 .$

Where we used the fact that $\lim_{n}\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{n}=\left\Vert f\right\Vert _{\infty}
 .$

Comment: Yes. The proof is correct. Although I would advise for the sake of rigour to use limsup and liminf wherever applicable since the limits of the quantities in question are not known to exist beforehand.